# What is Drools Kie?

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, kie

I need help in KIE API. Need to know that what it is and is there any tutorial available to use Drools KIE. Is kie part of drools-6.x ? And if it is part of drools-6.x then what will be the effect on applications using Drool-5.5 running JBPM5.4, and guvnor 5.5 ?

Regards,

Zahid Ahmed

Comment: Got here by Googling "What does Drools KIE stand for", the answer: Knowledge Is Everything.

Comment: @nickb thanks I was simply wondering what KIE stood for.  From the Drools [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e32), _"A new umbrella name, KIE (Knowledge Is Everything), has been introduced to bring our related technologies together under one roof. It also acts as the core shared around for our projects. So expect to see it a lot."_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Drools6 and jBPM6 are introducing a new public API called kie-api.  It is very similar to the Drools5 and jBPM5 API in a lot of areas, but some areas were added or refactored as well.  The API itself should have full Javadocs, and more documentation is currently under development as well.

For people using the old knowledge-api from Drools5 and jBPM5, this is still backwards compatible, so you should be able to use either

Comment: Actually, some of the package names may have changed
org.drools.spi.KnowledgeHelper; (5.x)
vs 
org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper; (6.x+)